# How can I open external applications on a main window on C++?

Tags: c++, win32gui, createprocess

I am creating a GUI where the screen is basically divided into seperate sub-windows for apps such as IE, music player, photo viewer, etc. I know that I can open these apps on external windows via createProcess but can anyone tell me how to open these on the tiles that are on the main GUI window?

Comment: Generally you can't. Some applications (like IE) can be *embedded* using [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by embedded and on how to utilize COM?

Comment: "How to utilize COM" is not a suitable question for SO - it is too broad. There are (large) books on the subject.

Comment: In particular, the apps you embed have to be written in a way which allows them to be embedded.  IE has, but Chrome and Firefox haven't.  I don't know if the default Windows music player is embedable, but I bet most 3rd party ones aren't.

Comment: It is *possible* to enumerrate a launched process's windows (see `EnumWindows()` and `EnumThreadWindows()`) and re-parent them into your own UI (see `SetParent()`), but it is generally [dangerous to do so](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) if the launched process was not written to be used that way (which most are not).